Pytest assertion problem for HTTPException: 500
I am having problem about testing a very simple FastAPI end-point and not able to assert HTTPException: 500.
This is my endpoint get AuthenticationRequest from client to get a token from an external system. AuthenticationRequest is nothing but a Username and Password combination.
@authentication_router.post("/authenticate", tags=["Authentication"])
async def authenticate(
    authentication_request: AuthenticationRequest,
    authentication_service: AuthenticationService = Depends()
):
    """
    Authenticate user and retrieve access token.

    Args:v
        authentication_request (AuthenticationRequest): User authentication request.

    Returns:
        dict: Access token if authentication is successful.
    """
    try:
        access_token = authentication_service.authenticate(authentication_request)
        if access_token is None:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid credentials")
        logger.info(f"Authentication is successful for user: {authentication_request.username}")
        return {"access_token": access_token}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception("An error occurred during authentication")
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))

I can successfully test this end-point with valid credentials (test_valid_authentication() works). However, invalid_credentials case does not work for me since Pytest did not assert status_code=500.
Here is my unit tests:
test_data = ApplicationConfiguration()


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return TestClient(authentication_router)


def test_valid_authentication(client):
    authentication_data = {"username": test_data.TEST_USER, "password": test_data.TEST_PASSWORD}
    response = client.post("/authenticate", json=authentication_data)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert "access_token" in response.json()


def test_invalid_authentication(client):
    authentication_data = {"username": "invalid_user", "password": "invalid_password"}
    response = client.post("/authenticate", json=authentication_data)
    assert response.status_code == 500

Since I am using another client at my endpoint, I am wrapping original 401 error with another exception status code which is 500.
I was expecting this test to be successful as well since I am asserting response.status_code == 500 in my test.
I want to pass my test_invalid_authentication() according to response status code = 500.
Could you please help about the missing point here.
Pytest Results:
    @authentication_router.post("/authenticate", tags=["Authentication"])
    async def authenticate(
        authentication_request: AuthenticationRequest,
        authentication_service: AuthenticationService = Depends()
    ):
        """
        Authenticate user and retrieve access token.

        Args:v
            authentication_request (AuthenticationRequest): User authentication request.

        Returns:
            dict: Access token if authentication is successful.
        """
        try:
            access_token = authentication_service.authenticate(authentication_request)
            if access_token is None:
>               raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid credentials")
E               fastapi.exceptions.HTTPException: 401: Invalid credentials

routers\authentication.py:28: HTTPException

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

   @authentication_router.post("/authenticate", tags=["Authentication"])
    async def authenticate(
        authentication_request: AuthenticationRequest,
        authentication_service: AuthenticationService = Depends()
    ):
        """
        Authenticate user and retrieve access token.

        Args:v
            authentication_request (AuthenticationRequest): User authentication request.

        Returns:
            dict: Access token if authentication is successful.
        """
        try:
            access_token = authentication_service.authenticate(authentication_request)
            if access_token is None:
                raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid credentials")
            logger.info(f"Authentication is successful for user: {authentication_request.username}")
            return {"access_token": access_token}
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception("An error occurred during authentication")
>           raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
E           fastapi.exceptions.HTTPException: 500: 401: Invalid credentials


====================================================================== short test summary info ======================================================================= 
FAILED tests\test_authentication.py::test_invalid_authentication - fastapi.exceptions.HTTPException: 500: 401: Invalid credentials
============================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed, 4 warnings in 1.46s =============================================================== 


This simplified code example works fine for me.
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/authenticate")
def authenticate():
    try:
        access_token = None
        if access_token is None:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid credentials")
        return {"access_token": access_token}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))



client = TestClient(app)

def test_invalid_authentication():
    authentication_data = {"username": "invalid_user", "password": "invalid_password"}
    response = client.post("/authenticate", json=authentication_data)
    assert response.status_code == 500


I think your code also should work.
If not, try to create minimal code example that reproduces the problem. So that we can just copy and run it.

That simplified version works for me too. I think problem starts when project is divided into modules. You can re-produce the problem by setting up following module structure:
PROJECT_NAME/
├── application/
│   ├── main.py
│   ├── routers/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── authentication.py
│   ├── tests/
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── test_authentication.py

main.py:
from fastapi import FastAPI
from routers.authentication import authentication_router

app = FastAPI()

# Set up routes
app.include_router(authentication_router)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        import uvicorn
        uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
    except Exception as e:
        # Log any unhandled exceptions during startup
        print(f"An error occurred during application startup: {e}")
        # Reraise the exception to terminate the application
        raise

test_authentication.py:
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from routers.authentication import authentication_router
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def client():
    return TestClient(authentication_router)


def test_invalid_authentication(client):
    authentication_data = {"username": "invalid_user", "password": "invalid_password"}
    response = client.post("/authenticate", json=authentication_data)
    assert response.status_code == 500

authentication.py:
from fastapi import HTTPException, APIRouter

authentication_router = APIRouter()

@authentication_router.post("/authenticate", tags=["Authentication"])
async def authenticate():
    try:
        access_token = None
        if access_token is None:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid credentials")
        return {"access_token": access_token}
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e)) from e

Since there are seperated modules run tests with python -m pytest at root level of application folder to produce the issue

I think the problem can be that you pass authentication_router (which is an instance of APIRouter class) as a parameter to TestClient instead of app (instance of FastAPI class).

That is definitely the reason, thanks Yuri. Weird thing is it was asserting HTTP 200 with the same way.
